# Can't get jquery show() to show the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, show

I'm ready to throw my pc through the window, somehow I can't seem to find my mistake. I feel like I am going insane. I have a simple login page in which you enter a name and a room code then you press submit. After you press submit I want to hide the form and show an element that says you are connected to the server. I'm using the following ejs/HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Login</title>
        <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link href="/assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="/assets/zoomFriendsAjax.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.3/socket.io.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <script src="/assets/sockets.js"></script>
        <h2>Welcome To ZoomFriends</h2>

        <div id="pagecontent">
          <div id="serverform">
            <form>
              <label for="servercode"><strong>Server Code:</strong></label>
              <input type="text" id="servercode" name="servercode" placeholder="Insert your server code here..." required>
              <label for="nickname"><strong>Your Nickname</strong></label>
              <input type="text" id="nickname" name="nickname" placeholder="Insert your nickname here..." required>
              <button type=submit>join room</button>
            </form>
          <div>
          <div id="connpage">
            <h2>Connected to server</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

and then there is this ajax js file, which activates on submit and contains a function to show connected which should show the "connpage" and hide the "form" it only does the latter:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


  $('#serverform').on('submit', function(){

      var player = $('input[type="text"]#nickname');
      var room = $('input[type="text"]#servercode');
      var joindata = {player: player.val(), room: room.val()};

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/button',
        data: joindata,
        success: function(data){

          serverconnected();

        }
      });




      return false;

  });

  function serverconnected(){
    $('#connpage').show();
    $('#serverform').hide();
  }

});
```

Then there is this css in which connpage is set to display: none;

```
body{
    background: #0d1521;
    font-family: tahoma;
    color: #989898;
    text-align: center;
}

#todo-table{
    position: relative;
    width: 95%;
    background: #090d13;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#todo-table form:after{
    margin: 0;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

#connpage{
    display: none;
}

input::placeholder {
  font-style: italic;
}

input[type="text"]{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    background:#181c22;
    border: 0;
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #989898;
    text-align: center;
}

label{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    background:#23282e;
    border: 0;
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #989898;
    text-align: center;
}

button{
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    background: #23282e;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 80px;
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

li{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

li:hover{
    text-decoration: line-through;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

h1{
    background: url(/assets/logo.png) no-repeat center;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-indent: -10000px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And this is the part of the server script that deals with the clicking of the submit button:

```
//if submit button is pressed
    app.post('/button', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
      //console.log("pushed the button")
      var message = req.body.player;
      var found = rooms.some(el => el.roomcode === req.body.room);
      if (found){
        var targetindex = rooms.findIndex(element => element.roomcode === req.body.room);
        io.to(rooms[targetindex].gamesocketid).emit('joinroom', {player: req.body.player, room: req.body.room, socket: socket.id});
        //var currentroom = rooms.find(element => element.roomcode === req.body.room);
        rooms[targetindex].players.push({nickname: req.body.player, id: socket.id});
        //currentroom.players.push({nickname: req.body.player, id: socket.id});
        console.log('player ' + req.body.player + ' joined room ' + req.body.room + ' with socket ID ' + socket.id);
        //console.log(currentroom);
        console.log(rooms[targetindex]);
        res.json(rooms[targetindex]);
      }
    });
```

as far as I know everything is going as it should, EXCEPT the connpage NEVER SHOWS, i get through every function, all data is logged the way I want, except `$('#connpage').show();` does nothing, it doesn't even have the common decency to send me an error or something ;p. Can anyone please help, I'm going nuts....  Eventually I need lots of show and hide to go on, to go through all the states of the page, without refreshing the page. Any help would really be welcome, thank you for even taking a look.

Comment: Have you already tried to set a console.log message to the function serverconnected() to check if this function is called?

Comment: @matthias_h I just added an alert and the function runs, I also suspected it ran, because it does hide the form.

Comment: Your best bet is to locate your from using the browser elements tab (right click on a control on the form and choose inspect) then locate the connpage and inspect the styles.  You may find a parent element is hidden or it's not on the page (offset=-1000) or something like that that you're not expecting.

Comment: You can not show it because it is inside of serverform! which you hide. Why? syntax error. A good editor will show you the error on the unclosed `</div>`

Comment: @freedomn-m  length = 1

Comment: Yes, we've established the issue.   If you locate it in the browser elements tab (inspect element) you'll see it's not where you expect it to be.

Comment: @epascarello OMG, i had a <div> tag where a </div> tag should be....   THANKS! I'm new to stackoverflow, how do I tag your help as the solution?

Comment: @SebastiaanvanWaardenberg you should close it as a typo - all the people answering are trying to be helpful, but essentially it's just a typo (as per the existing votes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your HTML. You never close your `serverform` TAG.That way your connpage is INSIDE that container and gets hidden too Change

```
<div id="serverform">
    ....
<div>
```

to

```
<div id="serverform">
...
</div>
```

Comment: i even didint pay attention to that ahahahah

Comment: Still won't work.

Comment: It works! I quite literally missed one "/" and it cost me 3 hours of my life...  You guys are amazing...

Answer (score -1):

normally `$("#connpage").show()`; should work, maybe in some part of your app you are overriding it, you can use `$('#connpage').css('display', '')` as an alternatif. 
if none of them work , you can remove the display none, and at the beginning you can hide it with `.hide()` .
i wish it helps

Comment: Nope. it won't work still

Comment: if there is no syntax error those should work ,

Comment: The point above is that if `.show()` doesn't work then neither will `.css('display', '')` nor css/.hide().

Comment: if those wont work it means there are some overriding somewhere or there are some problems in jquery code

Comment: It was because the div's were inside of each other, because instead of closing the serverform with a </div> tag, i just added another <div> tag.

Comment: yeah bro i think you got no syntax error, you can use some ide for not having those errors,,, #stayAtHomeAndCode :D